# I have a Woocommerce brand plugin, on the brand page, the descriptions appear on the products. How do I get this under products

Tags: wordpress

I have such a code, but the code adds a description to the bottom of the products, but does not delete the description at the top. I am using flatsome theme my plugin is yith brands

```
if ( class_exists( 'YITH_WCBR' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_wcbr_move_brand_description' ) ) {
    function yith_wcbr_move_brand_description() {
        if ( version_compare( WC()->version, '2.7.0', '>=' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description' );
        }

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', array( YITH_WCBR(), 'add_archive_brand_template' ), 7 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', array( YITH_WCBR(), 'add_archive_brand_template' ), 5 );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'yith_wcbr_move_brand_description' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the code in the premium version of the plugin is different

```
if ( class_exists( 'YITH_WCBR_Premium' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_wcbr_move_brand_description' ) ) {
    function yith_wcbr_move_brand_description() {
        if ( version_compare( WC()->version, '2.7.0', '>=' ) ) {
          remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description' );
        }

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', array( YITH_WCBR_Premium(), 'add_archive_brand_template' ), 7 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', array( YITH_WCBR_Premium(), 'add_archive_brand_template' ), 5 );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'yith_wcbr_move_brand_description' );
}
```